# SQL query find all entries which match ALL other entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Probably be better if I explain via data :)

Say if I have a table

```
ItemId  Identifier1 Identifier2
1       'Test 1'    NULL
1       'Test 2'    NULL
```

So `ItemId 1` is identified by 'Test 1' AND 'Test 2'. This could be a combination of Identifer1 or Identifier 2 e.g.

```
ItemId  Identifier1 Identifier2
1       'Test 1'    NULL
1        NULL       1
```

In this case `ItemId 1` is identified by 'Test 1' and the number 1. And Item can have as many rows to identify as is possible.

I want to find all records (in a table with same structure as above) which have duplicate identifiers.

My current incorrect approach validates with just one row, so

```
ItemId  Identifier1 Identifier2
1       'Test 1'    NULL
1       'Test 2'    NULL
```

and

```
ItemId  Identifier1 Identifier2
2       'Test 1'    NULL
2       'Test 3'    NULL
```

are coming back as duplicate records because of the 'Test 1' match. This is incorrect. It needs to check all rows.

I thought about using an 'ALL' but that didn't help! I imagine I would need to use some magic with an aggregate/window function, but I cannot come up with the correct query.

Please help!

Comment: Or maybe I can coalesce all identifying rows into a CSV row and compare on that? Not sure about this one...

Comment: You started off great by saying that you wanted to show us sample data.  Unfortunately, your question is still not clear.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry. Which part? Basically I want to find all item ids (first column) which have duplicate identifiers - An Identifier for an item are entries in the 'Identifier' columns (column 2 and 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find all items where all rows for the item match exactly the same rows for another item.

This is more complicated because you have two columns identifying each row and each `NULL`s are important.  But not too complicated:

```
SELECT t1.itemid, t2.itemid
FROM (SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid) AS cnt
      FROM table t
     ) t1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid) AS cnt
      FROM table t
     ) t2
     ON t1.itemId <> t2.itemId AND t1.cnt = t2.cnt AND
        (t1.identifier1 = t2.identifier1 OR t1.identifier1 IS NULL AND t2.identifier1 IS NULL) AND
        (t1.identifier2 = t2.identifier2 OR t1.identifier2 IS NULL AND t2.identifier2 IS NULL) 
GROUP BY t1.itemid, t2.itemid
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(t1.itemid) AND COUNT(*) = COUNT(t2.itemid);
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks. I will have a ponder over it :)

Comment: Actually wait. The query is still matching item1 with item2! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c718/1/0

Comment: I think you want to join on `t1.itemId < t2.itemId` (instead of `<>`) so you don't duplicate the results. And `HAVING MIN(t1.cnt) = COUNT(t1.itemid) AND MIN(t2.cnt) = COUNT(t2.itemid)`

Comment: Well I tried running it and the `having` clause still didn't seem right.

Comment: Huh? It worked fine for me in the scenarios I tested them in! - In the fiddle, it correctly returned no results. When I updated the records to have the same identifiers, it did return the records. In which scenario did you fail in?

Comment: Well I removed the old `having` rather than commenting and it seemed to work. SQL Fiddle can be so weird. Glad it work out :)

Comment: Yeah, I think I had basically (and inadvertently) commented out the entire `having` expression. I think SQL Fiddle strips line breaks or something. @Gordon, you did most of the work so I don't want to steal your answer away.

Comment: Indeed. Was working fine for me in SSMS. Weird few moments that was. Thanks all.